# Including many-to-many from another model in field in django admin interface

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Greetings,
I'm sure there is a simple solution to what I'm trying to do but unfortunately I wasn't able to find it in the documentation.

I have the following model (simplified version shown):

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
  student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True,
      db_index=True, max_length=9)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Course(models.Model):
  course_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True,
                              db_index=True, max_length=4)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  dept = models.CharField(max_length=6)
  number = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
  student_id = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s %s" % (self.dept, self.number)
```

What I wanted was to be able to add students to multiple classes in the admin interface similar to the way that I can add students in the classes admin interface. If there is yet another way that seems more beneficial I would be interested in that as well.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`inlines`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) in your related model, or [**`this`**](http://www.eivanov.com/2009/01/manytomany-relations-in-django.html) blog post might be of some help.

Comment: inlines won't package the many-to-many multi-select boxes though.

Comment: @Ranman You mean it wont give you the multiselect widget like the one in the admin form where your relationship reference is made. You can try the blog post. I've never used that method so i can't vouch for it. But it looks like what you are looking for.